# Possible to use BIOS interrupts in Forth?

Tags: forth

I am doing a class project comparing different programming languages. Is it possible to use BIOS interrupts in the Forth language? I can't seem to find any such information on this. If so what would be an example?

Comment: This question is specific to a particular implementation of `Forth`. Please tell us *exactly* what Forth are you using.

Comment: Well we are doing a project that compares different languages. For example, showing the class how the Hello World program is written in various languages. We are using FreeBSD to write our simple program in those languages. Then we noticed that the boot loader is using files with the .4th extension and we didn't know what that was. We investigated a bit and found it's actually a programming language and so we thought we could include it in our presentation list. Maybe extra marks for a language never mentioned in class!

Answer (score 5):

I think you're under a mistaken idea that there's a single all-encompassing "Forth" out there. There isn't. There are many Forth implementations. Those that run "bare bones" (without an OS) or under DOS can certainly be coaxed to access the BIOS APIs. Those that run under a 32 or 64 bit operating system like Windows or Linux are unlikely to provide such functionality, since the operating system makes it hard to run BIOS APIs to start with.

When running under Windows, using 16-bit BIOS *APIs* (as opposed to reading data without running BIOS code) is cumbersome. Modern BIOSes also offer 32-bit APIs, but in all cases you're limited to what hardware you can access (none) - this is enforced by the OS, not by the BIOS code.

Generally speaking, the BIOS APIs are cumbersome and there's no point to using them when you have a full-blown operating system available to you.

Now if you don't care much whether the BIOS calls access real hardware or emulated hardware, you can certainly use Forth to access something like [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com) and run the real BIOS on emulated hardware. Heck, DOSBox provides its own BIOS implementation :)